# The Physical Meaning of Node Voltages in Two Power Circuits Problem

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

When I solved a simple problem of node voltage, I came to the conclusion by combining two simple Ohm's law equations, but I did not know the physical meaning of this result.
[image]
**As the picture show,i want to get the vaule of $Uab$.**

Because the circuit has only one loop,so i have two formula about the Loop current:

$I=\frac {V2-V1}{R1+R2} (1)$

$I=\frac {Va-V2}{R2}  (2)$

because (1)(2) are equal,so i can get the $Uab$.

**The expresstion is $Uab=Va=V1+\frac {R1(V2-V1)}{R1+R2}(3)$ .**

Just like the follwing picture:
[image]
**This is where i can not understand:why is came out like this,the physical meaning of formula$(3)$ is what，Why $Uab$ voltage is related to electromotive force $V1$?**

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the voltmeter.  You have a loop (circuit) with two batteries opposing each other and two resistors in series.

The net voltage of the two batteries is 5V.  The total resistance is 20 ohms.  This means that 5/20 or 0.25 amps is flowing in the circuit.  So the voltage drop across a single resistor is 0.25 x 10, or 2.5V.

The current is flowing counter-clockwise through the circuit, meaning that the resistive voltage "drop" adds to the battery voltage on the left and subtracts from the battery voltage on the right.  So both sides end up with a net 12.5V.

Which is what you'd suspect if you examine the circuit again and realize that the two equal-valued resistors will cause the two voltages to be "averaged".